# Float: right; in <ul> (nav)

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, html-lists

i have simple css & html menu. it's fine, but i try to move some links to right, but when i try, all of these goes. i tried with inside  - and still nothing. Can someone help me?

```
#forum-nav,
#forum-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        width: 960px;

}
#forum-nav {
    float: left;
}
#forum-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
#forum-nav li a {
    display: block;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 2em;
    padding: 0 1.0em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#forum-nav ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    z-index: 999;
}
#forum-nav ul li a {
    width: 80px;
}
#forum-nav li:hover ul.dropdown {
    display: block; 
}


/* Main menu
------------------------------------------*/
#forum-nav {
    background:#597288;
}
#forum-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#forum-nav > li:hover > a {
    background: #889bac;
    color: #fff;
}

.active {
    background: #889bac;
    color: #fff;
}


/* Submenu
------------------------------------------*/
#forum-nav ul{
    margin-left: -20px;
}
#forum-nav ul a {
        border-top: 1.5px solid #fff;
        width: 100%;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
    background: #597288;
}
#forum-nav ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
#forum-nav ul li:hover a {
    background: #889bac;
}

#forum-nav ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
}
```

and html:

```
<ul id="forum-nav">
<id="m_index"><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
<id="m_index"><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
AND I WANT IN ON RIGHT
<id="m_index"><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
<id="m_index"><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
</ul>
```

how can i move it, and still it will be works fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you haven't actually defined any `li` elements within your `ul` so your markup is invalid, secondly you need to add a rule in your CSS to float the last two list items to the right.

Change your HTML to:

```
<ul id="forum-nav">
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
</ul>
```

And add to your CSS:

```
#forum-nav li:nth-child(3),#forum-nav li:nth-child(4){
    float:right;
}
```

nb. if you want to float all children other than the first two to the right you can use:

```
#forum-nav li:nth-child(n+3){
    float:right;
}
```

**nb.** per Chriz's answer- `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: if you want to share the same name then use class="m_index" instead of id

Answer (score 0):

**html**

```
<ul id="forum-nav">
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">LINK ON LEFT</a></li>
  AND I WANT IN ON RIGHT
  <li class='right'><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
  <li class='right'><a href="#">LINK ON RIGHT</a></li>
</ul>
```

**css**

```
.right { float:right; }
```

**Note** : give `li` open tag, and giving same `id` more element is not good practice, this CSS class`right` will do your job